# SQL Listar solo el ultimo movimiento

Tags: sql

Tengo una consulta en SQL que me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
Inmovilizado desde  Comprobante Código  Descripción                 Saldo
2022-03-17          AJN         3278    CAÑO NIV.1 110XMT.APRO  PVC 15677.80
2023-09-18          ENT         3278    CAÑO NIV.1 110XMT.APRO  PVC 15677.80
2022-08-20          FAC         3278    CAÑO NIV.1 110XMT.APRO  PVC 15677.80
2022-08-19          N/C         3278    CAÑO NIV.1 110XMT.APRO  PVC 15677.80
2024-01-30          REM         3278    CAÑO NIV.1 110XMT.APRO  PVC 15677.80
2023-03-14          SAL         3278    CAÑO NIV.1 110XMT.APRO  PVC 15677.80
2022-08-19          TRA         3278    CAÑO NIV.1 110XMT.APRO  PVC 15677.80
```

Pero yo solo quiero mostrar el registro con la fecha mas reciente, o sea, el resultado seria:

```
Inmovilizado desde  Comprobante Código   Descripción                    Saldo
2024-01-30          REM        3278      CAÑO NIV.1 110XMT.APRO  PVC    15677.80
```

El codigo SQL que tengo es este:

```
    select
max(STA14.FECHA_MOV) as [Inmovilizado desde],
    STA14.T_COMP AS [Comprobante],
    STA20.COD_ARTICU AS [Código] ,
    STA11.DESCRIPCIO AS [Descripción] ,
    STA19.SALDO as [Saldo]
from 

STA20 JOIN STA14 ON STA14.TCOMP_IN_S=STA20.TCOMP_IN_S AND STA14.NCOMP_IN_S=STA20.NCOMP_IN_S 
LEFT JOIN STA11 ON STA20.COD_ARTICU=STA11.COD_ARTICU 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT STA19.COD_ARTICU,SUM(STA19.CANT_STOCK) AS [SALDO] FROM STA19 GROUP BY STA19.COD_ARTICU) AS STA19 ON STA20.COD_ARTICU=STA19.COD_ARTICU
WHERE 

STA20.TIPO_MOV <> 'X' AND STA20.COD_ARTICU<>'' 
 AND 
 STA20.COD_ARTICU IN ( '3278' ) 

 group by
 STA20.COD_ARTICU,STA11.DESCRIPCIO,STA19.SALDO,STA14.T_COMP
```

Comment: ¿Es SQL Server? Además, ¿conocés los _CTE_?

Comment: Sí, es SQL Server. No sé que son los CTE.

Comment: Podrías order por fecha descendiente y sólo tomar el primero con `SELECT TOP 1 ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes lograrlo fácilmente encerrando toda tu consulta actual en un CTE, y de este quedarte solo con el primer registro ordenado descendentemente por fecha, por ejemplo

```sql
with
miCTE as (
TuConsultaActual
)
select top 1 *
  from miCTE
 order by [Inmovilizado desde] desc
```

Comment: Esto si funciona, con un articulo en particular y en principio resuelve mi pregunta.  Pero que pasa si quito el AND STA20.COD_ARTICU IN ( '3278' ) para que me muestre   solo el ultimo movimiento de todos los articulos.

Comment: @Plomero Eso es una pregunta diferente que involucra otro razonamiento y debería de ser otro post.

Comment: Muy bien, entendido.